# PHP Simple-HTML-Dom loop once then stop

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to **scrape** a webpage with PHP Simple Html Dom,
but there seems to be a problem with the loop process which only loop once and then stops, which should do several loops and stop.

Here is the URL I want to **scrape**: `http://anymart.c1.biz/index.html`.

Please show me where is the problem and show me the correct code.

Here's my code :

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');

        $url=('http://anymart.c1.biz/index.html');

$html = file_get_html($url);
$articles = [];
$i = 0;

foreach ($html->find('div.gallery-a table[width=745]') as $data) 
{
    if ($i > 5) 
    {
    break;
    }
    $title = $data->find('tr.*[id] > td > a.gal_title', $i);
    $item['title'] = $title->plaintext;
    
    $url = $data->find('tr.*[id] > td > a.gal_title', $i);
    $item['url'] = $url->href;
    
    $image = $data->find('img.gal_thumb', $i);
    $item['image'] = $image->src;
       
    $articles[] = $item;
    $i++;
}

$result = json_encode($articles, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);        
        
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-type: Application/JSON');
echo $result;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Provided site has only one table, so it works fine. You need to loop for `tr`.

Comment: @freeek i got this error loop for the tr "Trying to get property of non-object", also the $image is in different part.